# Specifying a Python metaclass in a parent class

Tags: python

If I have:

```
class MyMetaclass(type):
 def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
     if (#some logic is true):
        return type.__new__(cls,name,(DifferentGrandParent,), attrs)
     else:
        return type.__new__(cls,name, bases, attrs)

class Parent(GrandParent, metaclass = MyMetaClass):
  # implementation

class Child(Parent):
  # implementation
```

The intention is that:

`Child`  inherits from `Parent`, which inherits from (`GrandParent or DifferentGrandParent` depending on condition)

The question is: how often does `def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)` inside `class MyMetaclass(type):` get run?

Does it get run twice:

- Once when `Parent` class is imported (from importing the module)
- And a second time when `Child` class is imported which inherits from `Parent`

And to achieve that intention, should we put some checks inside `def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)`  to distinguish between the first and 2nd runs? That is, I don't want `#some logic is true` to run when `Child` class  is being created, only when the `Parent` class is being created.

Comment: `MyMetaclass.__new__` is the *constructor* of classes, it gets run any time you *create a new class with that metaclass*. So in this case, when `class Parent` and `class Child` get executed. So yes, it will get run twice (you can just put a print statement to see this for yourself, something like `print("creating new class", name)`)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks, actually i'm confused: why would ```class Parent``` be created *again* when ```class Child``` is created? Won't it just use the ```class Parent``` that was initially imported?

Comment: The `Parent` class isn't created again. I never said that. The `Parent` class is created once, and the `Child` class is created once, both times by the metaclass

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga why does the metaclass's __new__ needs to run when ```Child``` class is created ?

Comment: Because it is the metaclass of the child class now. So of course it will run. See: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#determining-the-appropriate-metaclass